# Find out how many tabs are opened in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is it possible to find out how many tabs opened are in IE browser using JavaScript?

I'm trying to resize IE programmatically and resizeTo does not work if IE has more than one tab opened.

Comment: No; that's not possible.

Comment: Please don't resize my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Save the current window size, then attempt the resize. If the new size is the same as the old, then either it failed or the window just happened to be exactly the right size. You can differentiate the two by resizing it again to something different.

Comment: *how many tabs opened are in IE browser using JavaScript?*

Comment: @NoobUnChained That is an XY Problem question. I am solving X.